# Heroku trying to install sqlite with every deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I know this question has been asked many times any I have tried all the suggested solutions and still can not get this to work:

I try to push an App to heroku and it is rejected because it tries to install the sqlite gem. I had sqlite as production db in the beginning but I changed and also tried to find all gems that have sqlite as a dependency, still heroku tries to install it.

I even tried taking/commenting it out everywhere. Help is MUCH appreciated!

Gemfile:

```
https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'sqlite3', :group => [:development, :test]

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'devise'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
  gem 'paymill'
  gem 'heroku'
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', :platforms=>[:mri_19, :mri_20, :rbx]
  gem 'hub', :require=>nil
  gem 'quiet_assets'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
group :production do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'pg'
end
group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require=>false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '1.0.1'
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem 'launchy'
end
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      mail (~> 2.5.3)
    actionpack (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
    activesupport (3.2.13)
      i18n (= 0.6.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.3.5)
    arel (3.0.2)
    atomic (1.1.14)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
    better_errors (1.0.1)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-datepicker-rails (1.1.1.7)
      railties (>= 3.0)
    bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.2)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    builder (3.0.4)
    cancan (1.6.10)
    capybara (2.1.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
    cucumber (1.3.8)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3)
      gherkin (~> 2.12.1)
      multi_json (>= 1.7.5, < 2.0)
      multi_test (>= 0.0.2)
    cucumber-rails (1.4.0)
      capybara (>= 1.1.2)
      cucumber (>= 1.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.0)
      rails (>= 3.0.0)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    database_cleaner (1.0.1)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    devise (3.1.0)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    diff-lcs (1.2.4)
    email_spec (1.5.0)
      launchy (~> 2.1)
      mail (~> 2.2)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.3)
    excon (0.25.3)
    execjs (2.0.1)
    factory_girl (4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
      factory_girl (~> 4.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    figaro (0.7.0)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      rails (>= 3, < 5)
    gherkin (2.12.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
    heroku (2.40.1)
      heroku-api (~> 0.3.7)
      launchy (>= 0.3.2)
      netrc (~> 0.7.7)
      rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
      rubyzip
    heroku-api (0.3.15)
      excon (~> 0.25.1)
    hike (1.2.3)
    hub (1.10.6)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (3.0.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.0)
    launchy (2.3.0)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.25)
    mini_portile (0.5.1)
    multi_json (1.8.0)
    multi_test (0.0.2)
    netrc (0.7.7)
    nokogiri (1.6.0)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    orm_adapter (0.4.0)
    paymill (0.4.0)
      json
    pg (0.16.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    quiet_assets (1.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.13)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      activerecord (= 3.2.13)
      activeresource (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.13)
    railties (3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.1.0)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rspec-core (2.14.5)
    rspec-expectations (2.14.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.14.3)
    rspec-rails (2.14.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
    rubyzip (1.0.0)
    sass (3.2.10)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    simple_form (2.1.0)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activemodel (~> 3.0)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.8)
    thin (1.5.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.18.1)
    thread_safe (0.1.3)
      atomic
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.37)
    uglifier (2.2.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  bootstrap-datepicker-rails
  bootstrap-sass
  cancan
  capybara
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  cucumber-rails
  database_cleaner (= 1.0.1)
  devise
  email_spec
  factory_girl_rails
  figaro
  heroku
  hub
  jquery-rails
  launchy
  paymill
  pg
  quiet_assets
  rails (= 3.2.13)
  rspec-rails
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  simple_form
  sqlite3
  thin
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out... I was not on the master branch ^^